# not a real dev, need help with an app to exit to home screen (or exit another application) on wifi disconnect.

Tags: android, android-wifi

Disclaimer: I haven't done coding or dev work in a very long time, and never on android.

Running in background mode, my app needs to detect when a particular wifi signal gets lost, and then it needs to return the user to the home screen. Bonus if I can get it to kill a specific application/process as the same time.

Is this possible? If so, any tips or help building it in next 24 hours?
Working on rooted motorola xoom, android 3.2.

Thus far I can tell tracking network state via either SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION
or NetworkInfo.DetailedState DISCONNECTING/DISCONNECTED should be viable options for monitoring the network status. What I haven't been able to yet find is how to get the app (without user action) to then return to home screen and/or exit the currently in use application... I am going to try and build this out tonight. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: so you want to "show up" the other developers, and get paid for this, but you want us to do the work for free? does that about sum it up?

Comment: I don't think that closing others app "unexpectedly" is a good practice, the users will think that the current app is "broken".

Answer (score 1):

Use the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). It's rooted, so install [Busybox](https://market.android.com/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en) or create a very simple script with the available tools which can be invoked from `init.rc`, something along these lines:

```
while :
do
if ping -c 1 www.google.com
then
   # there's connectivity, do whatever you want
   :
else
   # no connectivity
   # kill the app
   kill the-app-i-want-to-kill
   # return home
   am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.HOME
fi
sleep 30
done
```

Ahhh, and use the other 15h 45m to find somebody that could do this app correctly.